# sqlite problem : sqlite3.OperationalError: near "where": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, select, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert data from my crawler into my db without duplicate.

However,

**sqlite3.OperationalError: near "where": syntax error**

```
c.execute('insert into stocks(stocknum) values (?) where not exists(select * from stocks)',(stock_num,))
```

above is my code to insert. I'm sure there is a problem near "where" but I couldn't debug it.

Answer (score 3):

If I followed you correctl, you want to insert values that do not yet exist in column `stocknum`.

Your immediate problem is that your query is not valid SQLite syntax. You cannot use `values()` with a `where` clause, you would need to `select` instead:

```
insert into stocks(stocknum) 
select ? 
where not exists(select * from stocks)
```

Now this is valid SQL, but does not do what you want. It inserts only if `stocks` is entirely empty. You would need to *correlate* the subquery with the outer query (which requires passing the parameter twice, or using a subquery):

```
insert into stocks(stocknum) 
select ?
where not exists(select 1 from stocks where stocknum = ?)
```

Finally: if you are running SQLite 3.24 or higher, this is simpler achieved tiwh the [`on conflict` clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html). For this to work, you need a unique (or primary key) constraint on column `stocknum`. Then you can do:

```
insert into stocks(stocknum) 
values (?)
on conflict(stocknum) do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [`IGNORE`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/):

```
c.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO stocks(stocknum) values (?) where not exists(select * from stocks)',(stock_num,))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is ***%s*** not ***?***.You can find documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html)

```
query = 'insert into stocks(stocknum) values (%s) where not exists(select * from stocks)'
args = (stock_num)

c.execute(query,args)
```